# How to pass multiple parameters to a function calling onTap of SfCalender in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am using SfCalender and want to pass one more parameter to a callBack of onTap

```
                 SfCalendar(
                  dataSource: _getDataSource(snapshot.data.data),
                  view: CalendarView.month,
                  showNavigationArrow: true,
                  monthViewSettings: MonthViewSettings(
                    showAgenda: true,
                    agendaStyle: AgendaStyle(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                      appointmentTextStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white, fontSize: 13, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                      dateTextStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: primaryColor, fontSize: 13, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                    ),
                  ),
                  controller: _calendarController,
                  onTap: _openForm(array),
                )


         _openForm(CalendarTapDetails details) {
             //code

           }
```

Currently if I dont pass any argument to _openForm, CalenderDetails details have the values but I want to pass one array along with CalenderDetails details. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the SfCalendar library (and it is closed source), but I think you are trying to do that:

```dart
onTap: (details) => _openForm(details, array);

// ...
_openForm(CalendarTapDetails details, List myArray) { 
// code
}
```